# Convert Dropbox filesListFolder to treeview in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, treeview, dropbox

Dropbox API return an array of files and folders that I need to convert it to a treeview using javascript.
I plan on follow the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1U-KuLmtbs tutorial but I need to transform the returned array from Dropbox to an object formated as needed by the tutorial.

I already have the Dropbox part working and returning somethins like this:

`[
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "publico",
    "path_lower": "/publico",
    "path_display": "/publico",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAAAGQ"
  },
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "imagens",
    "path_lower": "/publico/imagens",
    "path_display": "/publico/imagens",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAAAjA"
  },
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "2018-12-10",
    "path_lower": "/publico/imagens/2018-12-10",
    "path_display": "/publico/imagens/2018-12-10",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAAAjQ"
  },
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "top100",
    "path_lower": "/publico/imagens/top100",
    "path_display": "/publico/imagens/top100",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAAAtw"
  },
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "vídeos",
    "path_lower": "/publico/vídeos",
    "path_display": "/publico/vídeos",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAABGw"
  },
  {
    ".tag": "folder",
    "name": "Vazia",
    "path_lower": "/publico/vídeos/vazia",
    "path_display": "/publico/vídeos/Vazia",
    "id": "id:AYnhiAeg5xAAAAAAAAABHQ"
  }
]`

And would need it to be transformed into something like this:

`{
  root: {
    name: '/',
    type: 'folder',
    path: '/publico',
    children: [
        {
          name: '/imagens',
          type: 'folder',
          path: '/publico/imagens',
          children: [
              {
                name: '/img.png',
                type: 'file',
                path: '/publico/imagens/img.png
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
}`

Thanks for your help.
Fernando